# Listview is not updating when 2nd time opening that fragment in Chat Application

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am working on a chat application using Xamarin.Android. whenever I get an incoming message or outgoing messages I am storing in a static collection. There is no problem while receiving and sending the messages from/to the server.

For the 1st time when I open the chat fragment, I am able to bind the view in the list for every incoming and outgoing message, going back from the chat fragment I am storing the all the chat details in a static collection.

Again when I open the chat fragment, I load all the static collection data in the list. after that When I get an incoming message, I am not able to see the updated view in the list, though it is stored in the static collection. when soft keyboard moves up or down and if I send any message I am able to view the newly arrived Message.

Everything I have updated in **RunOnUiThread** and after updating the list I have given `NotifyDataSetChanged()`.

Please provide a solution on this.

Comment: We need to see your code to understand whats up

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar kind of issue in which my layout was not getting updated. But the moment I used to touch the screen anywhere, the layout used to reflect the changes. I had a view and I was trying to change its visibility to View.GONE. If you are facing a similar kind of issue, you can try this

```
    view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }, 0);
```

It worked for me. Maybe your issue is also because of this.

Comment: Thanks Dude. Actually I tried this but No luck for me. @kashish Malhotra

Comment: Ok. Maybe if you post your code, we can find a solution.